# Can I assign a different radius when click a pie slice using Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts it is working fine but i want to change in pie slice when i click on single pie slice then that slice overlap two slice(right or left slice).

**Below is the image attached tha i have done in pie chart.**
[image]

**Below is the image attached of the expexted pie chart result**
[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have make some change to this code for re size all other pie.

: http://jsfiddle.net/8vd6cod1/2/

```js
function resizeSlice(point, change) {
  // Original shape params are stored in shapeArgs:
  var shape = point.shapeArgs;

  if (point.graphic) {
    point.graphic.attr({
      // "r" is outer radius:
      r: shape.r + change,
      // "innerR" is inner radius:
      innerR: shape.innerR - change
    });
  }
}

// Build the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
      // On window resize, apply change:
      redraw: function() {
        Highcharts.each(this.series[0].points, function(point) {
          resizeSlice(point, point.customResized ? 5 : 0)
        });
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      innerSize: '90%',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            Highcharts.each(this.series.points, function(point) {
               resizeSlice(point, 0)
            });
            var change = 0;
            // Custom param, can be called whatever we want:
            this.customResized = !this.customResized;

            if (this.customResized) {
              // Let's resize!
              change = 5;
            }

            resizeSlice(this, change);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [3, 4, 5, 6]
  }]
});
```

Comment: can you explain how your answer differs from Paweł Fus's answer.

Comment: In this solution, you can not resize multiple slices at the same time, only one. And it's buggy: click two slices, then resize browser..

Comment: This can also be solution http://jsfiddle.net/1wo8y6xm/  using variablepie

Answer (score 4):

You can add your own method, which will resize shape on click, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8vd6cod1/

```js
function resizeSlice(point, change) {
  // Original shape params are stored in shapeArgs:
  var shape = point.shapeArgs;

  if (point.graphic) {
    point.graphic.attr({
      // "r" is outer radius:
      r: shape.r + change,
      // "innerR" is inner radius:
      innerR: shape.innerR - change
    });
  }
}

// Build the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
      // On window resize, apply change:
      redraw: function() {
        Highcharts.each(this.series[0].points, function(point) {
          resizeSlice(point, point.customResized ? 5 : 0)
        });
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      innerSize: '90%',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            var change = 0;
            // Custom param, can be called whatever we want:
            this.customResized = !this.customResized;

            if (this.customResized) {
              // Let's resize!
              change = 5;
            }

            resizeSlice(this, change);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [3, 4, 5, 6]
  }]
});
```